# Test equality of different instances of a class

Tags: python, assert

I am trying to use assert() to check the content of a simple class without the need to check each of the members of the class. Is something like the following possible?

```
def class class_data(object):
    def __init__ (self, name = 'Richie', school = 'Jefferson High', age = 17):
        self.name = name
        self.school = school
        self.age = age


myschool = class_data()

#check for correct data via assert
assert (myschool == class_data('Fonzie', 'Lincoln High', 17))
```

Please excuse me if my questions is nonsensical, and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the [`__eq__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method on your class.

When you do `myschool == other`, Python will call `myschool.__eq__(other)`, which by default just whether checks both objects are the same (in your case, they aren't).

You can override `__eq__` to achieve your purpose, here's an example:

```
def class class_data(object):
    def __init__ (self, name = 'Richie', school = 'Jefferson High', age = 17):
        self.name = name
        self.school = school
        self.age = age

    def __eq__(self, other):
        for attr in ("name", "school", "age"):
            if getattr(self, attr) != getattr(other, attr):
                return False
        return True
```

Note: using `getattr` isn't necessarily the best thing to do here. The implementation you choose is up to you.